# Search Instagram user by name through API

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram, instagram-api

I'm trying to implement a search field on my webpage so you can search for publicly accessible Instagram profiles by name. The (now legacy) Instagram API had the endpoint `https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/search` for this but since April it has been deprecated (https://www.instagram.com/developer/changelog/#april-4-2018) an it is not accessible anymore (I tried myself).

I have been checking out the newly released Instagram Graph API (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api) but it is focused on Instagram business accounts and in any case, I haven't been able to find the relevant endpoint.

Does this mean that this functionality is not available anymore or did I miss something?

Comment: Don’t think that is available any more, no. Don’t see much point in having such a “feature” on an external website either, though … If I want to search instagram accounts, I would assume I could do that directly on the instagram website … so what exactly is the benefit your site would be offering me here?

Comment: As part of my application, users will create business cards and I want to allow them to link their social media accounts

Comment: Well then they might have to perform that search directly on instagram themselves now, resp. log in to their account there (probably quicker than searching, which would still have the potential that they pick a wrong one, if several with similar names exist or sth. like that.)